# why value types are declared (instantiated) without 'new' keyword in (vb or C#).net

Tags: .net-3.5

why  value  types are declared (instantiated) without 'new' keyword in (vb or C#).net

Comment: .NET does not have a "new" keyword. You have to indicate a specific language. Besides, your question is vague.

Answer (score 0):

Value types are not necessarily constructed without the use of the `new` keyword, but there's support in the language for primitive types, like integers, strings, etc.

In other words you typically write this:

```
int i = 10;
string s = "test";
```

However, if you define your own value types, to declare variables with initial values, you need to use `new`:

```
Point p = new Point(10, 20);
```

I think you need to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: You asked "why"... argh, I thought it said "what"

Comment: I think I know what he means, see my answer. Confused me too. :(

Answer (score 0):

Basically any primitive CLR type with the exception of Object does not require `new`.

There are ways to apply this to any (blittable) valuetype too, by going unsafe, pretty much similar too how things are done in C specifically in the embedded world.

Update:

You changed your question. It seems you have been misinformed. Unless you are talking about default values that happens at class initialization, which is still 'using' `new` under the covers.

Example:

```
class Foo
{
  Point foo;
}
```

When doing `new Foo()`, `foo`'s value is initialized to its default value, which implies `new Point()`.

The above code is effectively:

```
class Foo
{
  Point foo;
  Foo()
  {
    foo = default(Point); // which is new Point()
  }
}
```